# Generating Polynomials for the MPQS

Tags: rsa, factoring

I'm going to try and eventually factor RSA-100, but my current QS needs a lot of improvement, so I'm going to try and switch over to the MPQS.

I'm a bit confused as to how the MPQS works, which is correct:

1) Use the QS polynomial to generate X/Y pairs, then sieve with the "new" polynomial
2) Use the "new" polynomial to generate X/Y pairs, and also sieve with this polynomial

And generating the polynomials, I'm not sure which is correct:

1) *A* must be a square, B^2 - n must be a multiple of A so that B^2 - n = AC 
2) *A* must be a square multiplied by a factor in the factor base, everything else as in (1) being the same